# Explain the difference between Spark configurations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have to set the number of executors in my spark application as 20. While looking at the official documentation I'm confused which is a better config to set

- spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors = 20
- spark.executor.instances=20

I have the following config enabled

- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true

In what use case scenario will I use either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) documentation

1. spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors

> Initial number of executors to run if **dynamic allocation is enabled**.
>
> **If `--num-executors` (or **`spark.executor.instances`**) is set and larger
> than this value, it will be used as the initial number of executors**.

as you can see in the highlighted text it can be overwritten by --num-executors when it is set to a higher value then spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors.
basically, when your application starts it will launch **spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors** and then slowly increase till **spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors** when dynamic allocation enabled.

2. spark.executor.instances

> number of executors for **static** allocation.

In layman terms,
It is like saying I want x resources(spark.executor.instances) to finish a job

(OR)

I want min(x resources) and max(y resources) and initially(z resources) to finish a job...
condition (x<=z<=y) should always satisfy and your resources usage will be decided on the needed when your job is running.

when to use dynamic allocation?

when you have multiple **streaming applications** running on your cluster OR **on-demand spark-sql jobs**.most of the time your jobs might need few resources and almost remain idle only in big data stream chunks(peak hours) job might need more resource to process data otherwise cluster resources should be freed and used for other purposes.

Note: make sure to enable external shuffle service (spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true) when dynamic allocation is enabled.

> The purpose of the external shuffle service is to allow executors to
> be removed without deleting shuffle files written by them [(more
> detail)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html). The way to set up this service varies across cluster
> managers

Referrences :
https://dzone.com/articles/spark-dynamic-allocation

Comment: @Swati Singh please feel free to upvote or accept if it answers your question.